# Django: UnboundLocalError while making database query

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, matplotlib, django-views

I am trying to do a matplotlib bar chart on django. The data that will be used, will be queried from my database.

I came across this error when I run my code:

> UnboundLocalError at /graph.png local variable 'topic' referenced
>   before assignment

The code for matplotlib part are all correct as I tried running static data before and it worked. However, when I tried quering data from database, it causes this error on views.py. I have done this query many times before on different pages and working fine. But it doesn't work for this request. Why?

```
def bar_chart(request):
    #Topic Distribution
    topics = list(topic.objects.filter(subject_id=subj_id).order_by('id').values())

    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    N = 5
    ind = np.arange(N)
    width = 0.35

    group_labels = [] #list of x-axis tick labels
    y = [] #list of y-values
    total_marks = 0 #total marks
    for topic in topics:
        t_questions = question.objects.filter(topic_id=topic.id)
        if (len(t_questions) != 0):
            topic_marks = 0 #each topic starts at 0 marks distribution
            for t_question in topic_questions:
                topic_marks += t_question.marks #accumulate the marks
            total_marks += topic_marks
            y.append(topic_marks)
            group_labels.append(topic.title)
    for yval in y:
        yval = yval/total_marks * 100 #convert to percentage


    ax.bar(ind, y, width, color='r')
    ax.set_ylabel('Distribution in %')
    ax.set_title('Topic Distribution')
    ax.set_xticks(ind)
    ax.set_xticklabels(group_labels)
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
    response=HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)

    return response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
topics = list(topic.objects.filter(subject_id=subj_id).order_by('id').values())
```

<strike>If you are following the common naming conventions for models, yours is probably called Topic, so it should be</strike>

```
topics = list(Topic.objects.filter(subject_id=subj_id).order_by('id').values())
```

Otherwise you are likely missing an import.

It's caused by the local variable topic defined within the function and overshadowing the global one.

Comment: I did a global import to specify the models. Within the same views.py, I used it in many other defs. My model class name is definitely "topic", not "Topic". Still, the error is there.

Comment: Scratch it then. The error is caused by having a local variable topics defined in the same function. 


I suppose that's part of the reason for model class name convention.


Just rename your local variable to something else or import model class using an alias and it'll work.

Editing the answer.